# Imaginary part of semiconductors index of refraction

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics, refraction, complex-numbers, absorption

I understand that the index of refraction is complex and can be expressed as such: $ \widetilde{\eta} = \eta + i \kappa  $. However I’ve been searching for a bit and I am unable to find the derivation of why the imaginary part of the refractive index in semiconductors is as follows $$k = \frac{\lambda \alpha}{4 \pi}$$
Can someone demonstrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is the attenuation coefficient, such that $|E|^2 \propto e^{-\alpha x}$ it is, by pure identification, the definition of 
$\alpha$.

Let's write:

$$ E=E_0 \exp\big(i (n+ik)k_0 x\big) $$
where $k_0=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is the vacuum wave number.
You get then:
$$ E=E_0 e^{ink_0 x} e^{-k\,k_0\,x}$$

and

$$|E|^2=|E_0|^2 e^{-2k\,k_0\,x}$$

Hence $\alpha=2k\,k_0=
\frac{4\pi\, k}{\lambda}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: If you agree my answer, as your comment suggest, could you please consider to mark it as "accepted " ?